# How to do semi-transparent overlay

Tags: css

I am making my website on SquareSpace and I am beyond frustrated. 
I like to have a background (which squarespace offers user to do without code) and like to have some sort of semi-transparent cover on the portion of the background where the text is. I think it's called overlay(?). 
Squarespace allowed user to add CSS code. I have no idea what to do. I tried to google, youtube and etc. but I can't seem to find how to do this. Can someone help me? I would really appreciate it. I spent so much time trying to figure this out. What I am trying to do is something like this (http://blog.squarespace.com). There's background, and there's semi-transparent on the top that covers portion of the background.

Answer (score 5):

Add a div, set it to `position: fixed`, have all of it's location values (`top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`) at `0`, and give it an `rgba()` background.

Note that this will make anything under it unclickable (unless you also give it `pointer-events: none`).

**[Here is a jsFiddle example of the concept.](http://jsfiddle.net/vTpya/)**

Answer (score 2):

Madara Uchiha's answer will cover the entire visible window, not just part of it. It won't work on certain mobile devices, either (iirc, Android WebKit doesn't support `position: fixed`).

A better suggestion would be to do something like the following...

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    text
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /* You could alternatively float the div, this is just to get it to fit the text width */
    z-index: 0; /* Not strictly necessary, but establishes its own stacking context to make it easier to handle compound/multiple overlays */
}

.overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JSFiddle showing previous version, with which the text is affected by the overlay, and current version, with which the text is not (and usage of `pointer-events: none` is unnecessary): http://jsfiddle.net/LGq8f/1/

Of course, if you don't want as fine control over the overlay area that the inner div gives you, you could instead just use `display: inline-block` or `float: left`/`float: right`, plus the alpha-valued background color, on the text-wrapping div and skip the overlay div.